# How to use multiple values for IN clause using same parameter passed through kotlin

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Why the IN clause/operator is unable to retrieve type1,type2 rows from the table?

this is written in main.kt file

```
//if i write here **var type="type1"** then the DAO fetches correct result
 but i want to fetch both type1 and type2. So, I am writing it in following way 
and then passing the "type" variable as "bind variable" in DAO 
but nothing is fetched and the output is blank//

var type="'type1','type2'"
var  sq = runBlocking {qdatabase(applicationContext).getquizdao().engquest(type).shuffled()}
```

this is written in DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tabledata WHERE Subject='English' AND Qtype IN(:types)")
suspend fun engquest(types:String):List<quizdata>
```

This is the db.

```
Question|Subject| Qtype |
------  |-------|------ |
Quest1  |English| type1 |
Quest2  |English| type2 |
Quest3  |English| type3 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass array or list of types:

```kotlin
var type = listOf("type1", "type2")
var  sq = runBlocking {qdatabase(applicationContext).getquizdao().engquest(type).shuffled()}
```

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM tabledata WHERE Subject='English' AND Qtype IN(:types)")
suspend fun engquest(types:List<String>):List<quizdata>
```